# Can't display multiple data in select option using ionic

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to display the data I get from my database and I actually getting 2 data but only one data are displayed in my select option.

My code from my controller is this.

```
        var link = 'http://127.0.0.1/mobile/subject.php';
        var userid = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('loginDetails'));
        console.log(userid);


        $http.post(link, {userid: userid}).success(function(data){
        console.log(data);

        for(i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
        $scope.subject = data[i].SubjectName;
        //$("#datas").append("<div>"+$scope.subject+"</div>")
        } 

        })
        .error(function(err) {
        console.log(err)
        });
```

My html code look like this  {{subject}}  I only put the {{subject}} on my option and I think this part should be loop to display more than one data.

This are the data that i retrieved from my database [image: first data]

[image: 2nd data]

But this is the only data that display in my select option the 2nd data..
[[image: select option data[3]]

any help will be appreciated thank you :D I'm new to this so i'm getting confused.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through each subject on the front-end like an ng repeat on option or ng-option. The way you are trying to display it now it will only show the last item within the array. Try the code below taken from here, but customize it to fit your work. 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
<form name="myForm">
<label for="mySelect">Make a choice:</label>
<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect"
  ng-options="option.name for option in data.availableOptions track by option.id"
  ng-model="data.selectedOption"></select>
</form>
<hr>
<tt>option = {{data.selectedOption}}</tt><br/>
</div>
```

Another example, but again, you need to change it in some areas but the structure should remain the same:

```
<select ng-model="filterCondition.sub">
   <option ng-selected="{{sub.value == filterCondition.sub}}"
        ng-repeat="sub in subject"
        value="{{sub.value}}">
     {{sub.displayName}}
   </option>
</select>
```

Comment: If you show me the front-end code I an adjust this code I pasted in here to fit your needs for you.

Comment: sir what code do you need only the controller and html code sir?

Comment: <div class="select">
 <div class="list">
                <label class="item item-input item-select">
                    <div class="input-label" >
                        Select Subject
              </div>
              
                    <select>

                     
                        <option>  {{subject}}  </option>
                 
                     
                    </select>
                    </div>

Comment: Right. You should send over all of your html so I can see where you have placed your ng-controller like in my example above. Do you have anything that looks like?

Comment: `<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect"
  ng-options="option.name for option in subject track by option.id"
  ng-model="data.selectedOption"></select>`

Comment: subject is your array, I am not sure what your object data looks like so my above comment might not exactly fit your needs. If it's an array without any objects with key value pairs, then you will need to create objects that have key value pairs and have a key that is labeled selected, so that when an option is selected, the value can be changed to true.

Comment: Sir i didnt put any ng-controller on my html code because my controller is directly connected on my html code..

Comment: What does your view look like? That's what I am trying to see. Everyone will need to see it because they need to see what you are seeing when you are using Model, View, Controller. http://mcgivery.com/structure-of-an-ionic-app/

Comment: <ion-view hide-nav-bar="true">
<ion-content class="background2">
<div class="select">
 <div class="list">
                <label class="item item-input item-select">
                    <div class="input-label" >
                        Select Subject
              </div>

                    <select >
<option>{{subject}} </option>
                    </select>

                    </div>                                                                                               </ion-content> </ion-view>

Comment: `<div class="select"> 
   <div class="list"> 
    <label class="item item-input item-select"> 
     <div class="input-label"> 
      Select Subject 
     </div>
     <select ng-model="filterCondition">  
      <option ng-selected="{{sub.value == filterCondition.sub}}" ng-repeat="sub in subject" value="{{sub.value}}">
              {{sub}}
             </option>
     </select>
     </div>
    </label>
   </div>
  </div>` subject needs to be your array of objects or values, is that the case here?

Comment: what do you get when you console.log data? That will help a lot.

Comment: Everytime i use ng-repeat I always get this error Erro: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: sub in subject, Duplicate key: string:i, Duplicate value: i

Comment: when I console.log($scope.subject); the data i Get is Multimedia               New Trends